# Nodejs+mongodb Hacer find en diversas colecciones a la vez

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, búsquedas

Buenas, estoy haciendo una aplicación que para hacer un "traking" de como va un proceso he hecho 3 colecciones: pendiente, procesando, finalizado.

La primera pregunta es: hay alguna función para mover datos de una colección a otra? Lo que hago ahora es un insert y un remove.

La pregunta principal es: para chekear en que parte del proceso esta un fichero, tengo que hacer tres find() en las tres colecciones para ver donde se encuentra, o hay algún modo de hacer un find() en las 3 colecciones a la vez?

Muchas gracias!

**UPDATE 1:**

A petición del usuario amenadiel, y viendo que no se entiende demasiado la pregunta, pongo el código (que funciona como yo quiero) y me dicen si es lo correcto o si hay algo mas fácil:

```
db.collection("collection1").find().limit(3).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    result.forEach(function(element) {
        db.collection("collection1").deleteOne(element, function(err, obj) {
        if (err) throw err;
            db.collection("collection2").insertOne(element, function(err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Pues la idea es coger algunos elementos de una colección y moverlos a otra. Pero no todos los elementos de la colección, sino aquellos que yo quiera. Me extraña mucho que no haya una función para tal cosa, así que para eso pregunto.

Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: primera pregunta es con la funcion [copy]
 (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/ ), para la segunda pregunta necesitamos que nos de mas informacion de lo que quieres hacer aparte de tus collecciones

Comment: A ver, que lo he explicado mal xD
Para la pregunta 1, solo quiero mover un registro de una coleccion a otra, algo asi como un findOne&Copy(), la copyTo lo copia todo.

Para la pregunta 2: imaginate 3 colecciones iguales (la estructura, no los datos) pero con nombre distinto, pongamos a, b y c.
Quiero hacer un findOne->where id=xxxxxx en las 3 colecciones a la vez, para ver si se encuentra en alguna de ellas.

Comment: Vas a tener que completar tu pregunta con el código que tienes hoy. Con tu segundo comentario no basta para entender lo que quieres hacer